# Problems passing a string from one view to the controller ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem in the parameter query from my view to the controller

from this controller sent to the view

Controller1

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    Public ActionRelieve DetailPlannelEmployee (int [] DeductionsId)
    {


    if (DeductionsId! = null)
    {

    IList <string> Deductionsp = new List <string> ();
    for (int i = 0; i <DeductionsId.Length; i ++)
    {
    int idDeduction = DeductionsId [i];
    var Deduction = db.Tbl_Deducciones.FirstOrDefault (t => t.DedId == idDeduction);
    Deductionsp.Add (Deduction.DedId.ToString ());

    }
ViewBag.Deduccionesp
```

already in the view

```
<table class =" table table-xxs datatable-responsive ">
<thead>
<tr>

foreach (var Deduction in (List <string>) ViewBag.Deduccionesp) // Foreach of the selected deductions
{

<th> Deduction </ th>

}

</ tr>
</ thead>

<tbody>
```

But I need to send that ViewBag.Deduccionesp from that view to another controller

What is this?

```
`<li> <a href="@Url.Action("ExportarExcel","Planilla", new {DeduccionesM = ViewBag.Deduccionesp })"> <i class =" icon-file-excel position-left "> </ i> Export an Excel </a> </ li>
```

and in the other controller I'm trying to receive it

Controller 2

```
`public void ExportExcel (IList <int> DeductionsM)
{

} `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about routing.

@Url.Action("actionName","controllerName", "routeValue")

By default, it should be like "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"

Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

For example,

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Products","Details", 5)">...</a>
```

And passing the parameter,id, to the controller.

```
public IActionResult Details(int id) { ... }
```

If you want to pass a string, for example,

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ExportarExcel","Planilla", new { DeduccionesM = ViewBag.Deduccionesp })">...</a>
```

And the controller would be like,

```
public void ExportExcel (sting DeductionsM) { ... }
```

The type of parameter referes to the type of route value and the name of parameter refers to the name of route value, so you can change the string to another type such as IList .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass complex data between actions in this way.  I suggest you look at `TempData` which survives across consecutive HTTP requests.

[ViewData/ViewBag/TempData comparision blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/viewdata-vs-viewbag-vs-tempdata-in-mvc1)

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a bit of untested code, but you should get the idea of what you can try,

Create a form as form in the page you want to post(i.e the second page), the inside that form, do a forloop on your data

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(........))
{....
    @{
        var stringList = (List <string>) ViewBag.Deduccionesp;
        for(int i = 0; i < stringList.Count; i ++)
        {
           @Html.Hidden($"DeductionsM[{i}]",stringList[i])
        }
     }
  }
```

Then at the end, your link would then post this form that will have the values bound to the default ModelBinder.